# How will I overwrite a text-decoration underline coming from a library?

Tags: html, css

I am using a library which provides an underline like the one below.
I would like to overwrite it and not display the underline.

My attempt:

`.remove {
text-decoration: none !important;
}`

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
}

.un:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  transition: 300ms;
}

.un:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="un remove">Underlined Text - Or to be underlined</span>
```

Comment: How is the library adding the underline?

Comment: Why are you resetting `text-decoration` if the library doesn’t affect `text-decoration` in any way?

Comment: @ChrisWheeler the library is using the `un` class for the underline.

Comment: Ah I see, that's not an underline. It's a 1px div with a background colour. I see others have provide an answer for this for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually isn't an underline - you need to remove the `:after`

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
}

.un:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  transition: 300ms;
}

.un:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.un.remove:after {   /* hide after if it has remove */
   display:none;  
}
```

```html
<span class="un remove">Underlined Text - Or to be underlined</span>
```

Comment: you can also set `content: none` to after, if you wanna keep some of the after css.

Answer (score 1):

You juste have to remove content from pseudoelement after

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
}

.un:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  transition: 300ms;
}

.un:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.remove:after {
   content: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="un remove">Underlined Text - Or to be underlined</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to reset `text-decoration`? The library doesn’t use `text-decoration`s for the underline effect. You need to reset the things that the library actually changes, like the `width` of the `::after` pseudo-element of the `:hover` state of the `.un` class:

```css
.remove:hover::after{
  width: 0 !important;
}
```

Other possibilities include setting `content: none !important;` or `display: none !important;` on `.remove::after`.